# Passenger/Apache Rails on CentOS only works in Development but not Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, centos6

I've installed Passenger, Apache and Passenger Apache module following the instruction of this (tutorial)[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6] and all seems fine if in my http.conf I have `RackEnv production` If I use `RackEnv development` I get an error. Any idea why?

**EDIT: Nothing shows on apache log nor on the Rails log**

Here the portion of my `httpd.conf` that's relevant to the domain:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/passenger-5.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
        PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/passenger-5.0.6
        PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>

RackEnv production
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com
        # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ruby/myapp/public
      <Directory /var/www/html/ruby/myapp/public>
                # This relaxes Apache security settings.
                AllowOverride all
                # MultiViews must be turned off.
                Options -MultiViews
                # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
                #Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone tell me what's missing?

Comment: What error do you get? Do you see anything in apache.log indicating the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's the problem. There's nothing on apache log nor on the Rails app log.

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying to run rails console (in either mode)? This sounds like it could be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default passenger, if it can't save error to log, save full error to tmp directory.
Files mask - passenger-error-*.html
For example, please check you /tmp, on my system logs save to that place:

```
/tmp/passenger-error-J5xYtO.html
```

Comment: There's a `/tmp/passenger.Iydkbm5` folder, however there is no error file. I've even search like `sudo find . -name '*error*'` yet I got no results.